Unable to Disable SpringBoot Banner in 3.4.0
I'm using Spring Boot 3.4.0. I tried to disable banner programmatically and using configuration i.e. application.properties. But in both ways not able to disable it.
@SpringBootApplication 
public class SpringwebdemoApplication {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication app  = new SpringApplication(SpringwebdemoApplication.class);
    app.setBannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF);
    app.run(args);
}}

But it still printing the banner.

I tried in application.properties to set this property spring.main.banner-mode=off as well, but the banner is still printing.
Its basic Spring Boot app.
application.properties
spring.application.name=springwebdemo
server.port=8090
spring.main.banner-mode=off

and my pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.training</groupId>
<artifactId>springwebdemo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>springwebdemo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<url/>
<licenses>
    <license/>
</licenses>
<developers>
    <developer/>
</developers>
<scm>
    <connection/>
    <developerConnection/>
    <tag/>
    <url/>
</scm>
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


It works for me, so please provide a reproducer (including your pom etc. ). Also crossposting this in the github issue tracker isn't a nice thing to do either.

Please share your application.properties, you might have left spring.main.banner-mode set to console, overriding the configuration in your code.

Some dependencies or custom initializers can override spring boot settings. As @M.Deinum said, you should also review pom.xml (For example, spring-cloud can enable the banner again)
As a fast bug fix, you can create an empty banner.txt in your src/main/resources/ directory. This should force Spring to use it instead of default banner.
